# Xamarin forms creating Value Converter causing ResolveLibraryProjectImports task to fail

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have created the following converter

```
public class StringToNullableInt : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tmp))
            {
                return tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

However this causes any attempt to build the android app to error out saying

The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Windows.winmd, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

It's not even used or referenced anywhere yet. If I stop inheriting the IValueConverter everything builds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have referenced the wrong IValueConverter. Make sure that it is in the `Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter` namespace (see the Xamarin.Forms documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/)) and not in the `Windows` namespace (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter)).

Comment: I was mistakenly using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data